# chapter style with lateral bar

Tags: chapters, titlesec, book-design

Is is possible to have a different text/layout for the chapter page, and a vertical bar?
What I want to achieve is something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `tikz` is probably overkill here, but works. The following code must be compiled twice for the vertical rule to be correctly drawn.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
    {\normalfont\Huge\filright}%
    {\thechapter}%
    {25pt}
    {\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
        \draw ([xshift=-30pt]current page text area.north west)
            -- ([xshift=-30pt]current page text area.south west);}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foobar}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```