# Vertical lines across page for each chapter

Tags: chapters, book-design

I want to make a "title page" for each chapter of a book, and it should have two vertical lines across the page (one thicker than the other), and the name of the chapter, as shown in the image below.

[image]

I don't know how to make the vertical lines and I don't know how to make the "title page" for each chapter.

I am using Texmaker in Windows.

This is the code after I included the suggestion of Werner:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx, lipsum, lmodern}
\usepackage{geometry}
\title{Serpientes venenosas de Honduras}
\author{Gustavo A. Cruz}
\date{}

 \makeatletter
 \def\@makechapterhead#1{%
   \vspace*{50\p@}%
   \noindent\hspace*{.1\linewidth}\smash{\rule[-2\textheight]{5pt}{3\textheight}}% Thick rule
   \hspace{.05\linewidth}\smash{\rule[-2\textheight]{2pt}{3\textheight}}% Thin rule
   \hspace{.1\linewidth}%
   {\parbox[t]{\dimexpr.75\linewidth-7pt}{\raggedright
      \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \normalfont\bfseries\fontsize{30\p@}{36\p@}\selectfont
      \@chapapp\space \scalebox{2}{\thechapter}
     \par\nobreak
      \vskip 30\p@
      \fi
       \interlinepenalty\@M
       \fontsize{45\p@}{55\p@} \bfseries #1
      }
     }\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage}
    \def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
     \vspace*{50\p@}%
    \noindent\hspace*{.1\linewidth}\smash{\rule[-2\textheight]{5pt}{3\textheight}}%        Thick rule
   \hspace{.05\linewidth}\smash{\rule[-2\textheight]{2pt}{3\textheight}}% Thin rule
   \hspace{.1\linewidth}%
   {\parbox[t]{\dimexpr.75\linewidth-7pt}{\raggedright
   \fontsize{45\p@}{55\p@} \bfseries #1
   }
   }\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage}
  \makeatother
  \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} 
    \begin{document}
          \maketitle

\chapter*{Agradecimiento}
 \lipsum[1]
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Can you post an image (even handmade) of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108853/chapter-style-with-lateral-bar?rq=1

Comment: Relevant: [Totally sweet horizontal rules in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32711/totally-sweet-horizontal-rules-in-latex).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a really old-school approach to reproduce the layout:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum,lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{graphicx,lipsum,lm}
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  \noindent\hspace*{.1\linewidth}\smash{\rule[-2\textheight]{5pt}{3\textheight}}% Thick rule
  \hspace{.05\linewidth}\smash{\rule[-2\textheight]{2pt}{3\textheight}}% Thin rule
  \hspace{.1\linewidth}%
  {\parbox[t]{\dimexpr.75\linewidth-7pt}{\raggedright
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \normalfont\bfseries\fontsize{30\p@}{36\p@}\selectfont
        \@chapapp\space \scalebox{2}{\thechapter}
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 30\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \fontsize{45\p@}{55\p@} \bfseries #1
    }
  }\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  \noindent\hspace*{.1\linewidth}\smash{\rule[-2\textheight]{5pt}{3\textheight}}% Thick rule
  \hspace{.05\linewidth}\smash{\rule[-2\textheight]{2pt}{3\textheight}}% Thin rule
  \hspace{.1\linewidth}%
  {\parbox[t]{\dimexpr.75\linewidth-7pt}{\raggedright
    \fontsize{45\p@}{55\p@} \bfseries #1
    }
  }\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Name of the chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter*{Name of the chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

The chapter title macros `\@makechapterhead` and `\@makeschapterhead` are redefined (respectively used to set the header of a numbered and unnumbered/starred chapter). [`lmodern`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lm) provides scaled fonts that can be enlarged beyond `\Huge` (the default for chapter titles), together with some [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) scaling of the chapter number... why not.

Page numbers are removed using `\thispagestyle{empty}` (default used to be `plain`).

Comment: Would this work for the book class?

Comment: @Anthea: Absolutely! I am also confident there will be more flair added in the form of `tikz` solutions (hence my reference to going old-school).

Comment: I tried pasting it into my document and I have the following error message: Missing \endcsname inserted. <to be read again>. \protect \lipsum[1]

Comment: @Anthea: It's hard to tell in comments what you're missing. You could edit your original post to include something that reproduces this error...

Comment: Despite the error messages, the output is like I wanted it.

Comment: @Anthea It seems that `babel` with `spanish` option doesn't like `lipsum`... Anyway this has nothing to do with Werner's code.

Comment: @Anthea Try with `\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman]{babel}`

Comment: Is there a way to remove the "lorem ipsum..." from the output?

Comment: @Anthea: The *Lorem Ipsum* output is from the [`lipsum` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) - it just provides dummy text. Remove `\lipsum[1]` from the example give in the answer, as well as `\usepackage{lipsum}`.

Comment: Just another question: is there a way to center the name of the chapter?

Comment: And is there a way to exclude the table of contents from this?

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to use tikzpicture.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{tikz,everypage,lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\bm@line{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]  % book mark
\node (A) [xshift=5cm] at (current page.north west){};
\node (B) [xshift=5cm] at (current page.south west){};
\node (C) [xshift=6cm] at (current page.north west){};
\node (D) [xshift=6cm] at (current page.south west){};
\draw [black, line width=3pt] (A)--(B);
\draw [black, line width=1.5pt] (C)--(D);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\chapter*{\protect\hspace{5cm}First Chapter}
\makeatletter
\AddThispageHook{\bm@line}
\makeatother
\clearpage
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Here I define a bookmark line where the position can be changed. everypage package is also needed.

[image]