# How can i add a line to contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm a beginner of LaTeX,recently I'm using the `tableofcontents` and `{titletoc}` to custom my contents,but here is a problem that confuse me a long time.

How can i make a line like this?(which follow the section's length)

[image]
wish your help.

Comment: please give us a minimal example of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapting the answer from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108853/chapter-style-with-lateral-bar):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}


\begin{document}

%\maketitle


\tableofcontents
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
        \draw[color=cyan] ([xshift=-14pt]current page text area.north west)
            -- ([xshift=-14pt,yshift=6cm]current page text area.west);


\section{Introduction}
\section{A}
\section{B}
\section{C}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can adapt `xshif` and `yshift` to your needs, color the line, or whatever.

Comment: Thinku too much : )